# Searching between columns and worksheets for strings that might have several gramatical errors or are written in a sentence

Tags: excel, vba, string

So I attempted to use this code to compare two columns between each other, as it is supposedly a much more efficient alternative to vlookup. The code compares the columns and then copy/pastes the matching values to a different column. The source of the code is answer #26 on the following link on MrExcel forums (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1043185-vlookup-vba-alternative-3.html#post5014908).

My current problem with the code is that I cannot seem to get it working for string values in general. I've tried several different things from Countif, Wordif, Chardif to various different ways of manipulating strings found on the Ultimate Guide to String Functions and I never got any results.

Once working for string values I would like to have it find strings that have missing letters, superfluous letters, sometimes two letters are different within a word, almost never more than 3 letters are different and sometimes the strings occur in a sentence.

Without a doubt there is something wrong with my code, or maybe I am going about it the wrong way. As with my previous posts I will be working on this table and if I find a solution like with my last two questions I will post it, but this one looks like it is much harder to solve.

Examples of the mispellings and sentences are:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjSWY.jpg)

Sorry about the text format of the colums, but I could not get https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ to work for me

Column 1:

nbaol®, eraba, eraba, licstclaieaaanli, cdia, cdia, daeic, daeic, xcalea, xcalea, rxedeaa, aneoisstafmalg, ilargc, litaol, aletna, oialrat

Column 2:

nbaaol® eraba  i.e. aravcvv.  eraba  i.e. aravcvv, licstclaieaanli 10 XM/5 XM , cdia (ЛАКАЛД) , прДпДпоеДеноАК, cdia (ЛАКАЛД)  прДпДпоеДеноАК , daeic 150SL/250SL čteblpa aeslopjaošitj arsšmemnnd , cdia (ЛАКАЛД)  прДпДпоеДеноАК , daeic 150SL/250SL čteblpa aeslopjaošitj arsšmemnnd , xcalea , rlmciém lcoeéplpui. rxedsseaa Mara555 + Kara 645, aneoitamalg 15 BL ðforga, litaol 10 XM/5 XM (ЛАКАЛД)  прДпДпоеДеноАК , aletna-MORA, oialrat®, oialrat  nbaol® eraba

Links Im working with:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/486708-compare-two-strings-find-difference-2.html#post4291032

https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-string-functions/#InStr_Description_ofParameters

Here is the code from the website. I removed the  For kk = 2 To 18 par of the code as I do not yet need multiple column copied

```
   Sub testlookup()

    Dim lastrow, lastrow2, i As Long
    Dim Searchfor, j, inarr As Variant

    'Data Dump Sheet
     With Sheets("Sheet 2")
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    inarr = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 20))
     End With

       'Values to look up & paste Sheet
         With Sheets("Sheet 1")
         lastrow2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

         ' load variant array with sercha variables
         searcharr = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow2, 1))

       ' define an output aray
       outarr = Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastrow2, 19))
     End With

     On Error Resume Next
     For i = 2 To lastrow2
     For j = 2 To lastrow

     Searchfor = searcharr(i, 1)
     If inarr(j, 1) = Searchfor Then
    outarr(i, 3) = inarr(j, 1)

       Exit For
       End If
      Next j
      Next i

     ' writeout the output array
     With Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastrow2, 19)) = outarr

 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you after a fuzzy look-up?

Comment: It seems I am hehe, thanks for reminding me of fuzzy lookup, I completely forgot it existed. I will try and encorporate a function UDF into the above code and ask for additional help if I have any trouble

Comment: Sucks that fuzzy algorithms are CPU hungry. I will try and make the code so that if the exact matches are not found using the above algorithm, then fuzzy lookup runs on the computer.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html

Comment: do you have any ideas about why the above code wouldn't work for me when using it to compare exact strings?

Comment: Depends on what the problem is. Comment out the On Error line as that is just concealing problems. Try stepping through your code and using the locals window to see what's going on. Perhaps also post a screenshot of a small sample of data.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!